# EF Core automatically changes table name from setting to Settings

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an issue with the table name generated by EF Core. Can anyone please help?

I have a `Setting` entity with EF config as

```
public class SettingConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Setting>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Setting> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.ToTable<Setting>(typeof(Setting).Name.ToLower());
        builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsRequired().HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(c => c.UserId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("userId");
        builder.Property(c => c.ShowEmail).IsRequired().HasColumnName("showEmail");
    }
}
```

However, when I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`, I got

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Settings",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                UserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ShowEmail = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Settings", x => x.Id);
            });
```

I have another entity named `Post` with EF configuration as

```
public class PostConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.ToTable<Post>(typeof(Post).Name.ToLower());
        builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsRequired().HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(c => c.Title).IsUnicode().IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200).HasColumnName("title");
        builder.Property(c => c.Comment).IsUnicode().IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000).HasColumnName("comment");
    }
}
```

The table name generated by EF Core is `post`, which is as expected.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "post",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    title = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: false),
                    comment = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 1000, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_post", x => x.id);
                });
```

Comment: Btw typeof can be replaced with nameof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the convention, you define a model as singular, and the EF will create the table name as plural.

if you want to break away from that, give a `[Table("YourTableName")]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you j4rey, let me have a try. However, not sure why `Post` entity is not changed. Please see the example I gave in my question. Actually, I have many other entities but only the `Setting` has some problem.

Comment: Hi @j4rey, seems like adding the attribute solves the problem but I don't understand why the issue only happens for `Setting` but others